# Meteor local server log: stream error Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: meteor

The following error seems to have appeared overnight, and is not identified with any community package that I can tell. Seems to be part of the core DDP and WebSocket modules.

`stream error Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`

It shows up in the log generated when starting the server. mike:mocha Mocha testing also seems to have broken.

Again, seems to have cropped up out of nowhere after having the app running correctly for a long time. May have been due to a `meteor update`. Meteor version is currently Meteor `1.1.0.2`.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you have a package or code on your server side that connects to another server using DDP or Websockets and there is an interruption where the server you're connecting to has a proxy and the underlying server goes offline.

This can happen from time to time. When you use websockets the connection is persisted for a very long time. It will immediately try to reconnect if there is a disconnection.

Nearly no cloud hosting provider is able to give 100% uptime so you can expect a few of these when there is an interruption. The error comes from trying to reconnect at this moment most likely.

If you have no package that bears this remote websocket connection attribute it could be meteor's package reporting system itself. You could opt out of this by adding the `package-stats-opt-out` package using `meteor add package-stats-opt-out`